# latex-preview-pane-update couldn't find "pdflatex" directory when emacs loading hello.tex

Tags: emacs, latex, executable-path

I run my hello.tex file. But it always has the warning:

> Error running timer ‘latex-preview-pane-update’: (file-error
>   "Searching for program" "No such file or directory" "pdflatex")

I've checked .emacs file. I've been adding script in .emacs.

```
(setenv "PATH" "/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH" t)
(latex-preview-pane-enable)
```

But it still dosen't work.
How can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `exec-path`. Your solution should work with `call-process-shell-command`, but that uses `call-process`. So, you want something like

```
(cl-pushnew "/Library/TeX/texbin" exec-path :test #'equal)
```

Then, you can check the program is found with `(executable-find "pdflatex")`.

Comment: Thank you! After your solution it works now:) But another question, why PDF couldn't display well. I got the information on the right window
%PDF-1.5
%–‘≈ÿ
3 0 obj
<<
/Length 485       
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream

Comment: @DylanYang I don't use that package, you should probably ask a new question as that sounds like an unrelated problem.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate for your help. After your instructions it woks now:)